# Crystal Reports Legal Size Landscape Printing Issue in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: printing, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

I am using Crystal Reports inside Visual Studio 2005.  I have created a report that is Legal Size, landscape.  When I print out the report, the margins are at least an inch and the report prints all of the columns on two separate pages.  I am printing directly out of Visual Studio.  The printer is Xerox WorkCentre 5225 PS (in case that's the issue).

I have changed the preferences to be Legal, the Layout to be Landscape and the image options to have no margins.  Still, the report prints incorrectly.

Also, under Page Setup, I've set all margins to 0.

Does anyone have any ideas?  I've search Google and this site and I cannot seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set the margins to 1 inch (2.54cm); instead of 0 and then use all of the available "white space" space on the report.

In my experience; all the "white space" on the crystal report will be printed; and is centered on the printed sheet.  Setting the margins reduces the available space but will ensure you have the correct space around your report.